# Problem deleting item with redux-toolkit action

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux-toolkit

I have a server-side delete router with the code to delete an item from a MongoDB server as;

```
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
 try {
   const devproject = await Devproject.findById(req.params.id);

   // Find the dev project by ID

   if (!devproject.toString()) {
     return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Dev project not found' });
   }

   // Delete the dev project from the database
   await Devproject.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);

   // Delete the file from the uploads folder
   const filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'uploads', devproject.filename);
   fs.unlinkSync(filePath);

   res.json({ msg: 'Dev project and file deleted' });
 } catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
   res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Server error' });
 }
});
```

The code works on postman as I can just call the route...

```
http://localhost:8080/api/devprojects/640aed0e55e07ef3c6143d2b
```

and it deletes the item.
However, it throws an error log...

```
[2023-03-10 12:06:02 GMT+1] DELETE /api/devprojects/[object%20Object] 500 22 - 1.416 ms
```

...when trying to call the action in the frontend.
The frontend code is this;

```
import { createAction, createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:8080';
export const deleteDevProjectById = createAsyncThunk(
  'devprojects/deleteDevProjectById',
  async (_id, thunkAPI) => {
    console.log('Deleting dev project with ID:', _id);
    try {
      await axios.delete(`${url}/api/devprojects/${_id}`);
      return _id;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);
export const devprojectSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'devprojects',
  initialState: {
    devprojects: [],
    devproject: null,
    loading: false,
    error: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    clearField: (state) => {
      state.devproject = null;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
builder
.addCase(deleteDevProjectById.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(deleteDevProjectById.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.devprojects = state.devprojects.filter(
          (devproject) => devproject._id !== action.payload._id
        );
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(deleteDevProjectById.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.error.msg;
      })
..........
  },
});
export default devprojectSlice.reducer;
```

I called the action in a component as..

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
  deleteDevProjectById,
} from '../features/devproject/devprojectSlice';
import ImageComponent from './ImageComponent';

const RenderDevProj = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { devprojects } = useSelector((state) => state.devprojects);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getDevProjects());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const handleDeleteId = (_id) => {
    dispatch(deleteDevProjectById(_id))
      .then((result) => {
        // handle success
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle error
        console.log('problem deleting');
      });
  };
  const sortedProjects = [...devprojects].sort((a, b) => {
    return new Date(b.createdAt) - new Date(a.createdAt);
  });
  return (
    <section className='grid grid-cols-3 '>
    {sortedProjects.map((project) => {
      return (
        <ImageComponent
          key={project.id}
          src={project.url}
          name={project.name}
          alt={project.filename}
          remove={handleDeleteId}
        />
      );
    })}
  </section>
  );
};

export default RenderDevProj;
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Let's work backwards from your error:

> [2023-03-10 12:06:02 GMT+1] DELETE /api/devprojects/[object%20Object] 500 22 - 1.416 ms

##### You are calling the API with a URL `/api/devprojects/[object%20Object]`.  This means you have an `object` somewhere that you should have a `string`.

So then you can look through the code to see how that URL is formed, and where you might be passing the wrong value.

```
export const deleteDevProjectById = createAsyncThunk(
  'devprojects/deleteDevProjectById',
  async (_id, thunkAPI) => {
    console.log('Deleting dev project with ID:', _id);
    try {
      await axios.delete(`${url}/api/devprojects/${_id}`);
      return _id;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);
```

Your thunk is called with a single argument `_id` which is intended to be a `string`.

##### Somewhere in your `ImageComponent` you are calling `remove({ _id })` when it should be `remove(_id)`.

I actually don't understand how you are doing that part, since the `remove` function requires the `_id` but you aren't passing the `_id` down to the `ImageComponent`.  Let's make it so that you can just call `remove()` with no arguments:

```
 {sortedProjects.map((project) => {
      return (
        <ImageComponent
          key={project.id}
          src={project.url}
          name={project.name}
          alt={project.filename}
          remove={() => {
            dispatch(deleteDevProjectById(project.id));
          }
        />
      );
    })}
```

You don't need to `catch` because the thunk always resolves.  It might resolve to an error but it will not reject.

There is also a disconnect between your reducer and your thunk.

The `return` value of the thunk becomes the `action.payload` of the `fulfilled` action.  You `return _id;` so the `action.payload` will be a `string`, once you call it correctly.

You need to change this line:

```
(devproject) => devproject._id !== action.payload._id
```

to:

```
(devproject) => devproject._id !== action.payload
```

because the `_id` is the entire payload.  It is not an `object`.